# preg_match Regex Matching Full String

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have a simple regex, but it's matching more than I want...

Basically, I'm trying to match certain operators (eg. `>` `<` `!=` `=`) followed by a string.

Regex:

```
/^(<=|>=|<>|!=|=|<|>)(.*)/
```

Example subject:

```
>42
```

What I'm getting:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => string '>42' (length=3)
  1 => string '>' (length=1)
  2 => string '42' (length=2)
```

What I'm trying to get:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => string '>' (length=1)
  1 => string '42' (length=2)
```

What I don't understand is that my regex works perfectly on  [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/hJ3zB0/1)

**Edit: To clarify, how can I get rid of the full string match?**

Comment: That's identical to what I already have...

Comment: You can't. Another way is to shift the matches array: `array_shift($matches)`

Answer (score 2):

Your answer is correct.`Group(0)` is the `whole match`.`Group(1)` if first group and `group(2)` is the second group.

Comment: Is there not a way to exclude the `whole match`?

Answer (score 1):

You are getting all 3 groups `\0`, `\1`, and '\2'. [see the group matching at the bottom of the page](https://regex101.com/r/hJ3zB0/2)

assuming your matches are in `$matches` you can run `array_shift($matches)` to remove the '\0' match if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Not only will `sscanf()` return the exact desired flat array, it will cast that number (after the comparison symbols) as an integer.  If a float is possible, use `%f` instead if `%d`.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/L5vaA))

```
var_export(
    sscanf('>42', '%[<=>!]%d')
);
```

Comment: Have you tried using !>42 for the value.

Comment: This answer works perfectly to extract the two segments.  This answer is not built to validate.  I do not interpret this question to require validation.  The asked question is matching a string that starts with operator symbols which I find odd/uncommon.

Comment: *Basically, I'm trying to match certain operators (eg. > < != =) followed by a string.* so saying it works perfectly seems a bit of a stretch as it works for all sorts of non-sensical operators.  Just looking at a question without context seems to take out any value of the fact that it's a human asking for help, they may miss details or make assumptions we are not aware of.

Comment: I am not interpreting the question as you are.  My answer will satisfy for all test cases provided in the OP's regex101.com demo: https://regex101.com/r/hJ3zB0/1